# Change criteria for general e-mails to users of specific SE sites

Tags: feature-request, email

I recently got an email from Atwood asking for thoughts on [merging Audio Rec & Prod. with Video](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/questions/115/proposal-to-add-video-to-this-site) because:

> you have an account with more than 15 reputation at audio.stackexchange.com.

While I have a minor interest in the site, I've never posted or answered a question (aka made the ARP.SE account for the heck of it), so it's somewhat strange to get an email like that.

The criteria for those sorts of general emails should be adjusted to only hit users who are actually involved in the site, not effectively everyone (as I assume, and could be wrong, that most people populating new SE sites are going to get a free 100 rep off the bat from other sites)

Comment: **125** rep (same as downvoting) sounds like a good completely arbitrary guess with no statistics whatsoever.

Comment: @Renesis: Or perhaps the threshold should simply exclude the "free 100"? This would allow those who care about the site, but are new to stack exchange, to still be notified.