# Broken unsubscribe links in Super User spam

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

Yesterday, I got a DKIM-signed message from Super User with the subject "Check out the Super User Weekly Newsletter".  It has been eons since I used the account and, yep, I couldn't even recover the password for the account by providing the email address that the message was sent to.

The URLs in the email (e.g. one starts with https://stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe-newsletter/) are all 404s.  But the content looks legitimate.

Is this the result of some botched internal testing?

Comment: The link(s) are 404s?  This was not raised on the other question.

Comment: No-repro on the 404s. The ones I see have a code tacked on the end of the stub listed above, and go to the right place. Are you using the whole URL provided on the email, Mark?

Comment: @M. Tibbits: note that Mark said that the URL *starts* with the stub listed above. The link above returns a 404 for me, but the links I see in my email are longer, and go to the right place.

Comment: Oh sure thing.  Sorry 'bout that -- again, I didn't get the email / couldn't confirm.  Perhaps it was a word wrapping issue and he truncated the link?

Comment: @M. Tibbits I couldn't log in and I couldn't recover my password even when I gave it the email that the newsletter was sent to -- it said there was no such account.  Maybe the links only worked when you could log in with that account?

Comment: @mark odd, when I go to http://superuser.com/users/account-recovery and enter the email address on file at http://superuser.com/users/11816/hexmode I do indeed get "email sent"

Comment: @jeff atwood, I think the problem came because it wasn't clear that the account I created was particular to superuser.  I suspect the fact that I only used SuperUser a once a year or so ago led, in part, to the problem.  The emails I got didn't link to superuser to subscribe/unsubscribe -- they went to stackexchange -- so I didn't see the lost password link for superuser, I saw one for stackexchange and, not being a frequent user, didn't realize that they were different.  After all, I thought, if I can use stackexchange OpenID credentials to log in, then maybe that is where my log in is.

Answer (score 8):

A small number of people received broken unsubscribe links at the bottom of the one-time newsletter promotion email. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to track down the cause of this bug yet.

In the meantime:

- Mark, I've manually unsubscribed you from this list.
- If anyone else has been unable to unsubscribe, please email team@stackexchange.com, and we'll unsubscribe you immediately.

Sorry for the inconvenience.