# Why is StackHQ following me on Twitter?

Tags: support, twitter

I got an email today from Twitter, with the following:

> StackHQ @StackHQ is now following you (@NetherPhoenix).

Which is sort of surprising, considering:

- I have only one "normal" follower (And he's related to me, anyway)
- I don't use Twitter all that often, and have never had any interaction with Stack Exchange on Twitter
- I don't list my Twitter account anywhere on my profile or otherwise (though it is the same as the email address listed in my profile / the email I use for OpenID)

Given this, I am both confused as to *why* StackHQ is following me, and *how* StackHQ found out about my Twitter account in the first place.

What's going on here?

Comment: I had the same thing.  My Twitter account is used by me approximately never and is connected to my through none of my identities.  This is the [second time this week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102797/please-dont-send-me-email-that-i-didnt-ask-for) that my email address is misused, as such, I've removed it from my profile network wide (and got the neat "default Gravatar" as my "new" icon).

Comment: I'm starting a new "Why isn't StackHQ following me on Twitter" :( .... btw - [@wilhil](http://www.twitter.com/wilhil)!

Comment: Shouldn't be this a [tag:bug] tag?

Comment: @William where do I sign up for that?

Comment: @Paulo Only if you want Jeff to swoop in and retag it back to [support].

Comment: no "eeeeek!" in title?

Comment: @jin - 'naw. I'm pretty mellow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is, [CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) controls @StackHQ and I followed the few Twitter accounts I ran across, in an attempt to hopefully help promote the awesome users that contribute a bunch of stuff to our sites.

If you don't want @StackHQ to follow your Twitter activity, let me know.

Comment: More general, you can block specific users from following you on Twitter. May you pass other users in the future that you don't want under you followers, like all those SEO/Spam and similar people...

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Comment: Ps.  I love what the Chaos team is doing.  Just *had* to add the lolcat as I've had quite the crappy day.

Comment: We always appreciate a good lolcat. And feedback. We don't want to make anyone uncomfortable.

Comment: Pfft.  I prefer "Soon."